# Ошибка при установки библиотеки с GitHub

Tags: python, pycharm

Когда пытаюсь установить пакет выдаёт ошибку
Текст ошибки - Looking in indexes: https://github.com/LaughingLove/faceit_api.py.git/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faceit_api.py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for faceit_api.py

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А как ты пытаешься этот пакет установить? Ошибка похожа на `pip`, но эту библиотеку им невозможно поставить. В документации предлагают просто склонировать проект https://github.com/LaughingLove/faceit_api.py/#install

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что мне делать после того как я клонирую проект. Прости если задаю тупые вопросы, просто я новичок, но вынужден лезть в серьёзный проект

Comment: А устанавливал через package Repository , потом просто выбрал нужную библиотеку и нажал install